# Testing localstorage in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, junit, local-storage, junit4

I am currently attempting to write JUnit tests for some GWT components which utilize the HTML5 localStorage.  However, it seems that they will always fail because it isn't supported.

I haven't found any information online about a work-around or whether there are plans to support this.  Hopefully, someone will be able to respond and shed some light on this gap. :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be that HTMLUnit does not support local storage, or that GWT doesn't detect it. You might have to run your tests in a real browser, using the Manual run style and/or remote testing: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting.html

Comment: Also make sure you are using a relatively recent version of GWT - I believe that recent GWT uses HtmlUnit which supports html5 features, but older versions of GWT did not.